# How to understand "fill out Bingo Card", "punch oneself" and "get trolled"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, slang

From this [dtrace.conf(16) wrap-up](https://www.joyent.com/blog/dtrace-conf-16-wrap-up), I come across the following statement:

> Just to save you the time filling out your Cantrill Presentation Bingo Card: you can find me punching myself at 16:19, me offering unsolicited personal medical history at 20:11, and me getting trolled by unikernels at 38:25.

I can't figure out the whole sentence's meaning. Could anyone help to explain how to understand "`fill out Bingo Card`", "`punch oneself`" and "`get trolled`" here? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: It's unlikely that you will find someone conversant with _dtrace_ here. Try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dtrace). To _get trolled_ is to engage in an online discussion with someone whose objective is only to argue with you.

Comment: @NanXiao Have you checked out his presentation video at those time positions? -- BTW, you know Bingo and have a general idea how to play it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, as @DamkerngT pointed out, the times refer to the video where Cantrill is giving his presentation.  Cantrell is using this format as an attention grabbing way to explain where

The phrase "Cantrill Presentation Bingo Card" is used figuratively. Bryan Cantrell is the presenter and a "Bingo Card" is used to keep track of events (in the real game, random numbers) as they occur. Cantrell is a high energy, fast thinking technologist who is all over the place in his presentation (fun and arguably inspiring to watch).

Cantrill is famous in the Unix/Linux community for a one line answer to David Miller which can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.sun.hardware/wCd7fHnzHjw%5B76-100%5D) regarding Sun kernel performance (at the time Sun was the go-to technology).

At 16:19 in the video, he figuratively punches himself. The joke is that DTrace (a part of Sun Microsystems) had the marketing power of Sun behind it and should have become a mega company in its own right.  At the time, Sun was THE power house in performance computing.

At 38:25, Cantrill refers to the tweet of another kernel developer that unikernel developers should band together at the DTrace conference.

To understand the joke, you need to know: what a [unikernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unikernel) is, what [Dtrace is/does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace), why [unikernels are important](https://www.linux.com/blog/introducing-unik-build-and-run-unikernels-ease), and why Cantrill is important to the community.

To appreciate the joke, one needs to understand that operating system kernels are the minutia of minutia of computer programming and extremely important since everything is built on them. It also helps to realise that dealing at that level of detail that low in the stack is not possible for just anyone.  At 5:21 Cantrell asks the room how many OS kernel programmers there are at the conference and a majority of hands appear.